# Uninstall and reinstall the windows 8 operating system

Tags: linux, windows, uninstallation, reinstall

I have a genuine windows 8 installed in Dell inspiron 15, I have a requirement where I have to install a linux operating system.

Since I have the genuine copy of windows ***I would like to know if there is any procedure where I can uninstall, install linux and reinstall windows with the same genuineness***.
I can see the product key, in the properties of "Computer" if that can be used.

I had also checked for the refresh, reset and restore of windows but these procedures did not talk of non windows OS.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would need some more details to more accurately answer your questions but for now I will try to answer your questions, mostly with questions. :-)

First off, the product key you see in the properties of "Computer" is not the product key used to register the product. The real product key is normally in the format of XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX. However the key is encoded in your registry and either with a quick script or some software from somewhere like Nirsoft you can get it. Here is an example:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
MsgBox ConvertToKey(WshShell.RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE

\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DigitalProductId"))

Function ConvertToKey(Key)
Const KeyOffset = 52
i = 28
Chars = "BCDFGHJKMPQRTVWXY2346789"
Do
Cur = 0
x = 14
Do
Cur = Cur * 256
Cur = Key(x + KeyOffset) + Cur
Key(x + KeyOffset) = (Cur \ 24) And 255
Cur = Cur Mod 24
x = x -1
Loop While x >= 0
i = i -1
KeyOutput = Mid(Chars, Cur + 1, 1) & KeyOutput
If (((29 - i) Mod 6) = 0) And (i <> -1) Then
i = i -1
KeyOutput = "-" & KeyOutput
End If
Loop While i >= 0
ConvertToKey = KeyOutput
End Function
```

Save that in Notepad and save as a file like showmemykey.vbs and run it. Now for a caveat or two...

1) Normally there is a special version of Windows for manufacturers like Dell, HP, etc... it is different from the retail version of Windows. I tell you this because if you use an install other than what came with your computer, it won't likely work with the key you get from the script above. Good news, normally those installs also do not ask for a key when they recognize they are being installed on a Dell, HP, etc...

2) Backup your data... you didn't mention dual-booting so I assume you are wiping out Windows. You won't be installing back to the same configuration.

As for Linux... I don't know your scenario or reasons for why you HAVE to install Linux. But if you like Windows the best bet is to NOT install Linux or Dual-boot. Dual-booting is a whole other discussion.

So how do you install Linux by NOT installing it you ask? You use a bootable version on CD/DVD or Thumb Drive. There are ton of them out there... Ubuntu being the most common, Kali being the one of the most fun... I run several Linux distributions on an external Solid State HardDrive and also on a 64GB USB3 Thumb Drive. It doesn't have to be that fancy, they have distributions so small they easily run on 4GB SDCards.

As for restoring Windows after you overwrite it with Linux, the only real way you would get everything back EXACTLY how you had it before Linux would be to have an image of the drive before you install Linux, and when you are ready to go back, you restore that image. Lots of software out there for that. I use real forensic software such as AccessData FTK or Guidance Software EnCase which have free imagers... but there are others like TrueImage I think and a few others. Even Norton/Symantec Ghost still exists.

You could do the same with Linux. Image before Linux. Image when Linux is installed and you can switch back and forth. My only suggestion is to do that on a smaller drive. An image of a 250GB harddrive will be fairly large so you will need to have storage for it.

Again, my suggestion, especially if you are new to Linux... BOOTABLE! Difference between CD/DVD Bootable and USB Thumbdrive or HardDrive is that the CD/DVD is readonly. So when you reboot, all changes are lost.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The requirement to install Linux is to have a infrastructure server - Esxi server to create a virtual machine of a powered on machine into a physical machine instead of a installing it as virtual machine.
The powered on machine is a RHEL 7,
I want to control it through my personal computer with a windows 8 OS and installed with a Vmware  Vcenter Converter,
Currently I was trying with a server installed in a vmware, this method gave an error message saying "Ip address cannot be found".

Comment: The IP Address is a separate issue. Most likely has to do with your network configuration in VMWare. I think what you are saying is you want to take a VM (vmdk) and apply that VM to a physical system like a laptop and then use it? That isn't too difficult but the part you say about controlling it after you put it on a physical device confuses me. If you are referring to remote access like X-Windows or SSH then no problem. I'd be happy to add more to the answer later if I get more clarification.

Comment: By the controlling of the physical machine I meant, I would be using VM client and also we can use SSH too. the VM client and VM vcenter converter are installed in a windows 8 OS. The IP issue was that the new virtual machine could not get the IP address, After googling the same came to a conclusion that the procedure requires a DHCP server,   I used the alternate solution of using the static IP address. and also stopped all the firewall( dint work). Now I am hoping that an actual physical server may solve my problem :)